# Resuming a project where you left off

Tags: ide

Sometimes when I resume work on a project after a long break, I forget where in the many files and lines I stopped working.  I can usually find it after a minute, but I'm wondering if any popular IDEs have a built-in way to indicate where you stopped working.

I currently use XCode/C++, but I'm curious if other IDEs have this feature.

Obviously I could make an additional file, and I'll do that if there isn't a more elegant way.

Comment: The words you are looking for are 'task', 'context' and 'focus'.  For example, in eclipse [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/).

Comment: Adding onto that, Visual Studio has a quick feature that tracks TODO comments. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txtwdysk.aspx (Personally though I just keep a notepad for each project. My coworker uses Trello at the moment to keep his thoughts together. Seems like everyone I know has a different method). The idea though is at the end of the day or while you work you can quickly type "// TODO: Finish adding X here tomorrow." Useful if you have others that need to see it in the VCS.

Comment: Just don't ever close your IDE and never reboot your computer! That's how I do it.

Answer (score 6):

**Just check the last commit** you made to the versioning system,be it a local repository or a remote centralized one. You can list the files changed in that last commit and get a diff report. That should pretty well tell you where you left off.

If you don't use a source code versioning system, then you should.